# How to individually segment metrics in one report in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

In Google Analytics or Google Analytics API App script.

How can I view/pull data from 2 metrics are segmented on different dimensions?

ie
Dimension:page
Metric 1 :users segmented on demographic:gender:male
Metric 2 :users segmented on demographic:gender:female

ie How would I combine

```
    var resultsM = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(
    profileView, //view id
    dataStartDate,
    dataEndDate,
  'ga:users', //metrics  
  optArgsMale
 );
var resultsF = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(
    profileView, //view id
    dataStartDate,
    dataEndDate,
  'ga:users', //metrics  
  optArgsFemale
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

For this king of query I would use the filter property which support regex.
Typically if you want to pull data from the sources xxx or yyy, you would add to your query:
filter: "ga:source=~xxx|yyy"

The "=~" will tell the api you are passing a regex rather than an exact match ("==").